# Installing and Running Firefox Using Kubuntu

Tags: firefox, kubuntu

I keep trying to download and install Firefox. The Ark archive manager comes on. I then extract the file but all it does it give me the individual componets but I'm still unable to either open or run Firefox. I need explicit instructions of what to do, Should I save the file when prompted or do I open with Ark? And if I open with Ark, what steps do I need to take to actually get Firefox installed and running?

Comment: Open the Software Centre and install Firefox like any other piece of software. Ark should not be involved in installing Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to install Firefox from the compressed bundle from the Mozilla website. To install Firefox in Kubuntu, just run the Firefox Installer - just search "Firefox" from the K menu and it will come up. This will install Firefox automatically.

If that doesn't work, which it should, just install the `firefox` package. This can be done by searching "Firefox" in Muon, or opening a terminal and running `sudo apt-get install firefox`.

Comment: I have tried to search Firefox from the K menu and nothing comes up. I then opened a terminal and ran sudo apt-get install firefox 
The message follows: Package firefox is not available, but is referred to by another package.This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or       
is only available from another source                                   
E: Package firefox has no installation candidate  
Are there any alternatives to get Firefox installed?

Comment: Before running `sudo apt-get install firefox`, run `sudo apt-get update`. You can configure additional software sources in the Software Sources program, which you can access by opening Muon and going to Settings > Configure Software Sources. It's worth adding the Multiverse repository.